# Chinese date - string not recognized at a valid DateTime

Tags: c#, .net

I have a problem that has only occured since upgrading our application code base to .NET 4 and running on Windows 2012
This issue DOES NOT occur in .NET 2 (3/3.5) when on Windows 2012 or Windows 2008
This issue DOES NOT occur in .NET 4 on Windows 2008

Throughout the code base the statements similar to this are repeated.

```
var sDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy");
var dDate = DateTime.Parse(sDate);
```

Surprisingly this doesn't create as many issues are you might expect, however this no-longer works in the combination when the code is compiled to .NET 4 running on Windows 2012 for our Chinese customers, who run the application under the zh-CN culture. 
There has been a change to the value outputted for `DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy");` so for 3-March-2016 the following is outputted.

.NET 2.0 / Windows 2008 - `10-三月-2016`

.NET 4.0 / Windows 2012 - `10-3月-2016`

Parsing `10-3月-2016` will cause a format exception. Parsing `10-三月-2016` still works, in .NET 4 and Windows 2012.

Is there a simple solution to correct the output of DateTime.ToString() to output `10-三月-2016` instead of `10-三月-2016` thanks?

Comment: As you indicate, one would expect problems with that code. The best thing would be to use explicit format string for parsing since an explicit format string was used at `ToString` as well. Therefore `DateTime.ParseExact(sDate, "dd-MMM-yyyy", null)` corresponds to the `sDate` you have. With such consistent coding, there is some ___hope___ it will work will all cultures and all .NET versions and all OS versions and all Regional and Language settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Change the Format in Regional and Language Options.
2. if not solve the problem, try:

   ```
   CultureInfo culture = new CultureInfo("zh-cn"); // China, simple chinese.
   culture.DateTimeFormat.AbbreviatedMonthNames = new string[]{"一月","二月","三月","四月","五月","六月","七月","八月","九月","十月","十一月","十二月",""};
   ```

   redefined Simple Chinese AbbreviatedMonthNames.

Comment: Then to use that `culture` at this single thread, one could say: `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.ReadOnly(culture);` You would skip all of this if the original culture was not `zh` (Zhōngwén) related.

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime dateVAlue=new DateTime();

CultureInfo culture = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;

DateTimeStyles styles = DateTimeStyles.None;

DateTime.TryParse(datetimestring,culture, styles, out dateValue);
```

Comment: I'm really looking for a solution that does not require changing
 `var sDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy");`
 `var dDate = DateTime.Parse(sDate);`
These are so common it's high risk, and so far only impacts one customer. Looking for a solution to the Chinese culture/month issue trying to avoid the bigger code issue.